# C# converting a list of generated numbers into an int array

Tags: c#, arrays, vector

Again, I am a discrete mathematician, not a coder, but an trying to use C# for a paper I am working on and need some help.

I have a code to generate a set of random integers, based on user input, and printed them as a string separated by commas, but need to convert them into a vector (or an int array?). I am not exactly sure which is appropriate, but I cannot find much online about how to use either in C#. I need to be able to apply vector functions to them, so each entry still needs to be identifiable and an integer, but the vector needs to be able to vary in size depending on the user input.

Comment: What "vector functions" are you "applying to them"? If you tell us the type that those functions require we can give you the code to create that type.

Comment: Is your question about how to generate random integers (and is pseudo-random sufficient for your purposes?) or about converting integers you already have into a vector format? If the later, what input do you have?

Comment: @Eric I already have the random integers in a string, I need a method to convert them.

Comment: @Quantic the vector functions are mathematical equations such as summing up each term in the vector and taking the sign, counting the number of 1's in the vector, or simply outputting the first entry.

Comment: When you say vector functions, Do you mean storing variables inside dynamic array?

Comment: Did you use "Convert.ToInteger" method?

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a comma-delimited string, you can use the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to split it based on the commas into an array and then you can convert each of these values into it's appropriate integer using the [`Int32.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) methods respectively :

```
// The Split() method will yield an array, then the Select() statement
// will map each string value to it's appropriate integer and finally
// the last ToArray() call will make this into an actual array of integers
var output = input.Split(',').Select(n => Int32.Parse(n)).ToArray();
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vHu1kj). If you needed to explicitly ignore possible empty entries and whitespace, you could use the following adjusted example :

```
var output = input.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s.Trim()))
                  .ToArray();
```

An even safer approach still would be to only use values that could be properly parsed as integers via the [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method as seen below :

```
// Split your string, removing any empty entries
var output = strings.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(n => {
                         // A variable to store your value
                         int v;
                         // Attempt to parse it, store an indicator if the parse was
                         // successful (and store the value in your v parameter)
                         var success = Int32.TryParse(n, out v);
                         // Return an object containing your value and if it was successful
                         return new { Number = v, Successful = success };
                    })
                    // Now only select those that were successful
                    .Where(attempt => attempt.Successful)
                    // Grab only the numbers for the successful attempts
                    .Select(attempt => attempt.Number)
                    // Place this into an array
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: That is a correct answer to some question, but I'm not sure it is the answer to *this* question. The question is not well enough defined at this point.

Comment: The question is how to convert a string of comma-separated integers into an array, so this does answer *this* question.

Comment: what is "n" in this code? and yes this seems to be exactly what I asked Eric.... I do not understand why you feel the need to be so rude.

Comment: `n` in this content is used in a [lambda function](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda) to map each item that is contained in the results of the `Split()` method (a `string[]` as this point) to a specific function that will be performed on it (in this case, `n` will be passed into the `Int32.Parse()` method to be parsed as an integer). This will yield a collection of integers, which are then made into an `int[]` via the `ToArray()` call.

Comment: @Sarah [This example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dcN9P5) should walk you step-by-step through the process and give you an idea of what the content basically looks like after each step. Hopefully this can help clarify what is going if you are having trouble.

Comment: EricJ is right. When you've got random numbers in a string you already converted from int to string once. This answer, though correct, is making a U turn.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's not necessarily true, because she said the numbers are "based on user input", so there really is no telling how they were actually created. They could be typed into a console or text box, and therefore never actually stored anywhere as `Int32` yet.

Comment: the split command is working, but the Parse command is failing, any ideas why?

Comment: @Sarah: I'm glad that this answer helps you, but that is not at all clear from your question. I'm also sorry that you feel it is rude to point that out. I don't see it that way.

Comment: @Sarah There are a few things that you could try. Firstly, you can ensure that no empty values are considered after the split, additionally, you can call the `Trim()` function to actually remove any trailing or leading whitespace prior to parsing and finally, you'll want to ensure that all of your input is actually integers. This can be done programatically if needed. I'll provide an example of this shortly.